# React Native: How should I store/modify a "Subtotal" state? Redux, Local State, or Global Variable?

Tags: react-native, global-variables, react-redux, local-storage, state

I'm developing a shopping cart app that needs to store and modify a subtotal value. Ideally, when a user scans a product QR code the JSON data associated with the code is imported, then the "price" attribute is added to a Subtotal state (or subtracted if the product is later removed by the user).

Here is sample JSON data:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Pink Platform Sneakers With Velcro Straps",
  "business_name": "Foo Foo Shoes",
  "price": "59.99"
  "size": "11.5",
  "description": "Foo foo foo...",
  "image": "https://foofoo.com/products/images/image.jpg",
  "thumbnail": "https://foofoo.com/products/images/thumbnail.jpg"
}
```

The Subtotal state will need to be displayed and modified in different views: Home Page, Cart Page, Shipping Page, and Confirmation Page.

I'm currently using Redux to store the Product List state, should I use Redux to store the Subtotal as well? Or would it be better to initialize a local state variable to hold this value? Or maybe I should use a global scope variable? From what I understand global variables are frowned upon in React Native, but this seems to be the easiest and cleanest approach. Please let me know what you guys think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely keep the subtotal in Redux, especially if you're already using it. What you're describing is exactly the problem Redux was built to solve: handling shared state that needs to be modified and kept in sync in different parts of the app.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. That's the approach I'll take.